# Binning multidimensional array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 4d numpy array (these are stacks of imaging data) and would like to perform mean binning along all but one of the axes.

starting with say

```
x=np.random.random((3,100,100,100))
```

I want to apply binning to axes 1,2,3 with bin size 10 and average the values in each bin.

expected result would be an array of shape (3,10,10,10)

I have looked into np.reshape like so:

```
result=x.reshape(3,-1,10,100,100).mean(axis=1)
result=result.reshape(3,10,-1,10,100).mean(axis=2)
```

and so on, but this messes up the structure of the image arrays

is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Comment: It won't be the most efficient way, but how about using a mean filter and then decimating the samples?
If you like the idea I can find some code that does that.

Comment: If you don't mind interpolation you could look at ```scipy.ndimage.zoom```, eg. ```zoom(x, (1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1))```. However it is interpolation and not true averaging.

Comment: I would like to add that your problem is called "pooling" in the context of convolutional neural networks (as well as other image processing related things). More specifically this is average pooling with a windows size (10,10), and strides (10, 10). See https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AvgPool2d.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.measure

a = np.arange(36).reshape(6, 6)

b = skimage.measure.block_reduce(a, (2,2), np.mean)
```

output:

```
a = 
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35]]
b = 
[[ 3.5  5.5  7.5]
 [15.5 17.5 19.5]
 [27.5 29.5 31.5]]
```

But instead of my 2d example, you can do that for a block size of (1, 10, 10, 10) of your data.

Answer (score 2):

```
#block size 
bs = (10,10,10)
s = 1
shape = [3,
         x.shape[s+0]//bs[0], bs[0],
         x.shape[s+1]//bs[1], bs[1]
         x.shape[s+2]//bs[2], bs[2]]
result = x.reshape(*shape).mean(axis = (2,4,6))
```

Possibly a redundant answer at this point, but if you prefer not to use skimage then this should do the same thing.

Comment: I fail to see how this is different from the method op described and said it didn't work.
I'm not blaming. Actually curious about what I'm missing

Comment: The method in the question just takes the mean over the wrong axes I as far as I can see.

For example:
result=x.reshape(3,-1,10,100,100).mean(axis=1)

I believe this takes the mean over the values at index values of [0,10,20,30,40,...]

Answer (score 2):

In my experience `cooltools` (https://cooltools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) works terrific for rescaling (either up or down) images of any shape. Can be 1D, 2D, 3D etc.

```
from cooltools import numutils

a = np.random.random((3,100,100,100))

#down-sample
rescale1 = numutils.zoom_array(a, (3,10,10,10))
#up-sample
rescale2 = numutils.zoom_array(a, (3,200,200,200))

rescale1.shape, rescale2.shape

Out[1]: ((3, 10, 10, 10), (3, 200, 200, 200))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x=np.random.random((3,100,100,100))

x_resized=np.zeros((3,10,10,10))

for i in range(len(x_resized[0])):
    for j in range(len(x_resized[0][0])):
        for k in range(len(x_resized[0][0][0])):
            
            x_resized[0,i,j,k]=np.average(x[0,i*10:i*10+10,j*10:j*10+10,k*10:k*10+10])
            x_resized[1,i,j,k]=np.average(x[1,i*10:i*10+10,j*10:j*10+10,k*10:k*10+10])
            x_resized[2,i,j,k]=np.average(x[2,i*10:i*10+10,j*10:j*10+10,k*10:k*10+10])
```

which performs the averaging blockwise.