How to average every NxN block in a 2d numpy array
Let's say I have a 2d matrix that with shape (6, 4), that represents values at coordinates
array = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
                  [1, 1, 1, 1],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [1, 0, 1, 0],
                  [0, 0, 1, 1],
                  [1, 1, 1, 1]])

I want to create a new (3, 2) array 2x2_means containing the mean of each 2x2 block inside array
So, 2x2_means[0, 0] would be the mean of array[:2, :2]:
[[0, 0],
 [1, 1]]

2x2_means[0][1] would be the mean of array[:2, 2:]:
[[1, 0],
 [1, 1]]

I want to be able to do this with much larger array shapes as well (e.g. averaging 25x25 blocks of elements over a 1000x1000 array)

I retracted my close flag because the previous link was answering a different question. I cannot flag this post for close again but the solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67400465/8033585

This solution to this question is exactly what I needed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871083/how-can-i-vectorize-the-averaging-of-2x2-sub-arrays-of-numpy-array

Have you actually tried the solution from stackoverflow.com/a/67400465/8033585?

In [2]: arr = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
   ...:                   [1, 1, 1, 1],
   ...:                   [0, 0, 0, 0],
   ...:                   [1, 0, 1, 0],
   ...:                   [0, 0, 1, 1],
   ...:                   [1, 1, 1, 1]])

Reshape and transpose can be used to reconfigure the array into the desired blocks:
In [3]: arr.reshape(3,2,2,2)
Out[3]: 
array([[[[0, 0],
         [1, 0]],

        [[1, 1],
         [1, 1]]],


       [[[0, 0],
         [0, 0]],

        [[1, 0],
         [1, 0]]],


       [[[0, 0],
         [1, 1]],

        [[1, 1],
         [1, 1]]]])

In [4]: arr.reshape(3,2,2,2).transpose(0,2,1,3)
Out[4]: 
array([[[[0, 0],
         [1, 1]],

        [[1, 0],
         [1, 1]]],


       [[[0, 0],
         [1, 0]],

        [[0, 0],
         [1, 0]]],


       [[[0, 0],
         [1, 1]],

        [[1, 1],
         [1, 1]]]])

Now just take the mean on the last 2 dimensions:
In [5]: arr.reshape(3,2,2,2).transpose(0,2,1,3).mean(axis=(2,3))
Out[5]: 
array([[0.5 , 0.75],
       [0.25, 0.25],
       [0.5 , 1.  ]])

[4] is a view of the orginal, so doesn't consume extra memory.
or
In [6]: wds = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr,(2,2))

In [7]: wds.shape
Out[7]: (5, 3, 2, 2)

This makes overlapping windows, so we have select the non-overlapping subset:
In [8]: wds[::2,::2].shape
Out[8]: (3, 2, 2, 2)

In [9]: wds[::2,::2].mean((2,3))
Out[9]: 
array([[0.5 , 0.75],
       [0.25, 0.25],
       [0.5 , 1.  ]])

edit
The transpose isn't needed since the mean axes don't have to be adjacent.  I was thinking of the more common SO where people want a 2d array with rearranged blocks.

The reshape-based approach in this answer is probably the most efficient way to do this, but it has the disadvantage that it's very indirect, and it would be quite easy to mix-up the ordering of reshaped dimensions and accidentally compute the wrong result.
A more direct approach would be to use a 2D convolution, and sample-out the desired results:
from scipy.signal import convolve

kernel = np.ones((2, 2)) / 4
result = convolve(kernel, array, mode='valid')[::2,::2]
print(result)
# [[0.5  0.75]
#  [0.25 0.25]
#  [0.5  1.  ]]

